# Why do some lightning components have more methods / properties than others

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I've noticed that some lightning components don't have all of the same methods as others. For example, I instantiated an aura:html component and one of my custom components and the object definitions are substantially different. Is there a reason for this and are the differences in available properties documented somewhere for each of the components?

I was surprised I couldn't call destroy on the aura:html component

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is a SecureComponentRef and the second is a SecureComponent. SecureComponent is only passed into code that belongs to the component (e.g. its controller and renderer). In this context you are allowed to cmp.find(auraIdForSomeInternalPartOfYourImpl) and call getElement()/getElements() to access your implementation. SecureComponentRef is what you get in all other scenarios - those where you are referencing a component and should only have public API access to it (methods, attributes, events). This eliminates one of the most egregious implicit (and therefor unsupportable) dependency anti patterns:

```
var someComponentIDoNotOwn = cmp.find("foo"); 
var someInternalDOMDetailsIShouldNeverDependOn = someComponentIDoNotOwn.getElement();
```

or another variation on that theme: cmp.find("foo").find("bar") which reaches into the guts of another component and breaks encapsulation horridly.

Specific to ***.destroy()*** that looks like an oversight and I believe we need to add that to SecureComponentRef.