# Cannot get div element from lightning component when locker service is activated

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I have the following component in my dev org:

```
<aura:component implements='forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes' access='global'>
    <div aura:id='myDiv' id='myDiv' access='global'>Hello World!</div>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
</aura:component>
```

with the following controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var content = component.find('myDiv');
        debugger; 
    }
})
```

**EDIT:** and the following renderer:

```
({
  afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        var ret = component.superAfterRender();
        var content = component.find('myDiv');
        debugger;      

        return ret;
  },
  render: function(component, helper) {
        var ret = component.superRender();
        var content = component.find('myDiv');
        debugger;

        return ret;
  },
  rerender: function(component, helper) {
        var ret = component.superRerender();
        var content = component.find('myDiv');
        debugger;

        return ret;
  },
})
```

When I activate locker service, the content of my `content` variable in my controller is a

```
"SecureComponentRef: markup://aura:html {8:68;a} {myDiv}{ key: {"namespace":"myNamespace"} }"
```

On a `SecureComponentRef` there isn't any `getElement()` or `getElements` methods to access the DOM (to then bind some script).

I've tried the same function in different events, but I always get the `Ref`.

Being in the same namespace (aka the same component), why can't I access the `SecureComponent` instead?

(@Doug seems to say I should be able here: [Why do some lightning components have more methods / properties than others](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142742/why-do-some-lightning-components-have-more-methods-properties-than-others))

Comment: just guessing, is it maybe because you have aura:id as well as id for the div?

Comment: @Rao, already tried all possibilities (Auraid only, AuraId and id, and Id only)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access the DOM elements in the init handler before they have been rendered. Even if you use the native document.getElementById('myDiv') call inside the init handler with LockerService disabled, you'll get null back.

If you move your find('myDiv') call to a button click handler it will return the correct SecureComponent object.

Also, the access="global" on a div element won't do anything useful. That property is specifically for Aura types (components, attributes, etc).

**Edit (Nov. 16):**

From Doug's comment, for situations similar to this you may want to explore custom renderers. Handle with care though.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm?search_text=renderer

Comment: Like Trevor said this is working as designed and actually eliminates one of the most common timing/confusion bugs right from the docs: "Use the init event to initialize a component or fire an event after component construction but before rendering." Calling .getElement() inside of init event handlers generates some of the greatest volume of questions about why it does not work or sometimes works (its never supposed to work BTW). Locker is not just about security but also about clearing the minefield.

Comment: ... Another example is we will be eliminating the need to know about $A.getCallback() - something that nobody gets correct the first time. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm is an easy one to get wrong.

Comment: Another thing to look into if you are going to be working directly with the DOM is Renderers - most often a solid choice for the location of code that relies on the existence of DOM elements. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm?search_text=renderer

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I did try to bind myself on multiple events in the renderer. I've edited the post - I still get a `SecureComponentRef` in the `afterRender` in a custom renderer.

Comment: By the way, I did try `document.getElementById('myDiv')` on the `afterRender` and I have access to the DOM.

Should'nt component.find() also work? The element is rendered at this point.

Comment: Yes component.find() should return SecureComponent at this point. I copy/pasted your repro and I'm getting back SecureComponent. Not sure what's going on with your case. Is there any other code you've excluded that may be affecting this?

Comment: No, I literally only have this single component on a newly created Lightning community page.

Comment: Yes you're correct. I get the same behavior in my production org with your repro. In my dev org, which is targeted to Spring '17 release, the issue is fixed and afterRender is properly returning the SecureComponent instead of the ref. I'm still digging in to what recent change fixed the issue. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Doug Chasman / Trevor Bliss, what would be the best way to open a bug to you guys so we can have the fix in Winter17? Create an issue on the Aura github? https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Remove the "var content = component.find('myDiv');" line from your init handler. This is causing the SecureComponentRef to be cached within the framework so future calls (like in afterRender) return the ref instead of the SecureComponent. Let me know if this workaround works for you.

Comment: This is still a bug, though. I filed W-3510894 internally. The best way for you to track this would be to open a customer case and have them link your case to the above bug. I can't guarantee we will fix this in a patch, however, since there's a workaround and it really only happens due to incorrect component code (trying to get the DOM element before it's rendered). We'd have to gauge risk once we come up with a fix.